# auto save word document c#

Tags: c#, save, ms-office

I have a bit weird question but I have to get it done somehow, any help will be appreciated.

I have an application and it detects if word document is opened if it is it has to auto-save it. For example if I my program is running and I open ms office word program will detect it (done) and it has to save it (this is what I dont know). Program should be able to auto save file (save as) without asking user for any kind of information.

Comment: So what is the problem? Organize a separate thread that would save the document every X minutes without prompt.

Comment: @vissi I think he wants to know how to hook into an open Word process and to do the Word interop.